# Transfer users from one APK to another (Android)

Tags: android

I wrote an app about 2 years ago and it was the first app I ever wrote. It wasn't written very well because of my inexperience but it has had a decent number of installs since it's been on the Google Play Store. I have rewritten the app to support newer devices, and the architecture and technologies the new app uses are completely different than the old app. The old app stored all the user's data in a SQLite database. I'm really struggling trying to find a good way to migrate users from the old app to the new app. Is there an easy way to use the same namespace and sign this new APK the same as the old one so that users just get the new app as an update? Is there an easy and user friendly way to have the users install the new app and migrate their data to the new app?

Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you still have the Google account and sign keys you have used to create the first APK?

Comment: I'm pretty positive that I do. I haven't updated the app in over a year but I'm pretty confident that I do.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Playstore keeps track of different App versions on base of the package name and the versionCode (both given in the Android Manifest)

So for updating an existing App you have to:

- create an App with the same package name and a version code higher then the existing App
- sign the new App with the key you used for the existing App
- publish the App with your Developer account

([official HowTo](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en))

Regarding the data migration: if an App is **updated** by the user, the data folder is left untouched. This means you can access the DB in the new version of the App and do whatever you want with it:
run SQL statements, move the data to your new format or simply delete it

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a shot.